# Drag and drop view not visible after drag and drop finished

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-relativelayout

I am testing drag and drop feature in my app
I have relative layout that contains two text views
These two text views can be dragged and dropped from their initial position to anywhere in the layout

When I drag the text views they are able to be dragged anywhere on the screen but if I leave the view to drop it anywhere they are no more visible

I have used OnTouchListener() and OnDragListener() on the textviews

**help me solve this problem**

**my activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
private TextView tv1, tv2;
LayoutParams lParams;
private static final String msg = "DRAG EVENT TESTING";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bigTV);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smallTv);

    tv1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    tv1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    tv2.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

}

private class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {


        ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

        View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(dragData, shdwbldr, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }


}

private class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");


                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                lParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                lParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                v.setLayoutParams(lParams);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");


                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                // Do nothing
                break;


            default: break; 
        }
        return true;
    }


}

      }
```

**my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bigTV"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drag Me"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/smallTv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drag me too but slowly!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bigTV"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

move text views at appropriate coordinates on ACTION_DROP event.